# resizing animation on wikipedia

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you go to a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) in Chrome and ctrl+scrollup or ctrl+scrolldown the resize is done in an animation.

How is this achieved?

(In FF only the

```
  Read
  View source
  View history
```

links in the top right corner animate)

Comment: "Mouseup" meaning "scroll up?"

Comment: That sounds like it's just your OS or the browser zooming in & out for you.

Comment: It doesn't animate for me.  The page shifts a bit as the zoom level adjusts, but that's it.

Comment: Here's for font size http://jsfiddle.net/FuPC7/ (Google Chrome, as zooming adjusts font size in it.)

Comment: @qwertymk the second link on my answer has a ton of examples you can try, including a moving, color changing box (my personal favorite)

Comment: It animates under Opera 12.01, fwiw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you examine the CSS with Chrome's Inspector, you will find this rule:

```
body.vector-animateLayout div#content, body.vector-animateLayout div#footer {
  transition: margin-left 250ms,padding 250ms;
  -moz-transition: margin-left 250ms,padding 250ms;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left 250ms,padding 250ms;
  -o-transition: margin-left 250ms,padding 250ms;
}
```

This smoothly animates the `margin-left` and `padding` properties, which Webkit seem to modify when zooming in and out. Firefox should also animate, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia does not animate in most browsers, but there is animation attempting to go on. The first clue was the `vector-animate` class on the body of each page. Their load.js file (called at the bottom of each page) attempts to create an animated switch when users zoom in and out, but this is not supported in most browsers (only a lucky few). It does not work in most FF and IE versions.
The load JS file is found here:`//bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&amp;lang=de&amp;modules=site&amp;only=scripts&amp;skin=vector&amp;*`

In addition, they also use some CSS to try to animate this:

```
body.vector-animateLayout div#content, body.vector-animateLayout div#footer {
transition: margin-left 250ms,padding 250ms;
-moz-transition: margin-left 250ms,padding 250ms;
-webkit-transition: margin-left 250ms,padding 250ms;
-o-transition: margin-left 250ms,padding 250ms;
}
```

This would get the same effect for Webkit browsers. A Reference about this is found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp). As you will note, this `transitions` CSS3 property is not very well supported yet.

For more information on the support of this property, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FCSS_transitions).